# Как вывести ответ в JSON формате

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

Всем привет я хочу удалить все сообщения, и если сообщения удалились то мне должен придти ответ в JSON формате {"Все сообщения удалены"} Однако у меня пока выводит ответ без джейсона, просто текст и все сообщения удаляются

Мой Гитхаб https://github.com/fallen3019/vaadin-chat

После этого запроса все сообщения удаляются и должен придти ответ в виде джейсона, но сообщение приходит не в джейсон формате

```
curl -X DELETE "Content-Type: application/json" localhost:8080/api/delete
```

MessageRepository

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
    List<Message> findAllByUnread(boolean unread);

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM chatMessages", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Message> getAllfromTable();


    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM chatMessages WHERE id > :id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Message> getUnreadById(@Param("id") long id);

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM chatMessages LIMIT 10", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Message> getLastMessages();

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM chatMessages", nativeQuery = true)
    void clearBase();
}
```

RestController

```
public class RestController {

    @Autowired

    TimerTask timerTask;

    @Resource
    private final MessageService messageService;

    public RestController(MessageService messageService) {
        this.messageService = messageService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/getall")
    public List<Message> getAll () {
        return messageService.getAllMessages();
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/save")
    public MessageStatus saveMessage(@RequestBody Message chatMessage) {
        return messageService.add(chatMessage);
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/last")
    public List<Message> getLasts() {
        return (messageService.getLast());
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/unread")
    public void getUnreadMessages() {

        timerTask.run();
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/unread/byid")
    public List<Message> getUnreadById(@RequestBody InputMessage message) {
        return messageService.getUnreadById(message);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/api/delete")
    public String clearBase() {
        messageService.deleteMessages();
        return "Все сообщения удалены";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так и написать в контроллере

```
 return "{\"message\":\"Все сообщения удалены\"}";
```

Comment: у меня вывело, вообще так корректно?

Comment: да, ну или создавать объект-обертку для вашего сообщения, которая в итоге все равно преобразуется к этому.